# Using state variable in function, cannot read property x of undefined (Functional React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, functional-programming

I am using firebase with react functional components, I am defining `db` object in useEffect and setting the object to state like this :

```
const [Db, setDb] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    const db = firebase.database();
    setDb(db, checkStatus());
}, []);

const checkStatus = () => {

  Db.ref("orders")
    .once("value")
    .then(snapshot => {
        // do something
    });
}
```

I have given `checkStatus()` as a callback to `setDb()` which I belive will get executed after `setDb()` changes the state (normally calling `checkStatus()` in `useEffect()` also gives the same error). Now while calling `checkStatus()`, I get the following error :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined`

I believe `checkStatus()` is getting executed before state changed, which leads to `Db` being undefined. I cannot figure out a way to call a function after the state value is set to something, and what are the best practices while calling functions and using state as such.

Comment: You didn't set the init state value inside `useState()`

Comment: I think a better way is to create a separate module and export `db` from there because its constant all the time and you may need that in many components.

Comment: @keikai Setting init state to empty string gives `Db.ref() is not a function`, what should i set init state to if I don't have a firebase db reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use useEffect

```
const [Db, setDb] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    const db = firebase.database();
    setDb(db);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if(Db) {
    Db.ref("orders")
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
          // do something
      });
    }
}, [Db]);
```

Or you can set firebase in useState

```
const [Db, setDb] = useState(() => firebase.database());

useEffect(() => {
    Db.ref("orders")
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
          // do something
      });
}, []);
```

Comment: You should have check `if(Db){...}` in second `useEffect`. Because it will be called at the first time.

Comment: @MaheerAli yes correct at start it will be undefined

Comment: This is cool, I will be waiting for some more answers to what others have to say before accepting :), thanks for replying

Comment: @jokerster Yes sure we are here too check how best we can do for codes

Comment: Change `useState(firebase.database())` to `useState(() => firebase.database())`. Then React will only call the function once to initialize the state. If you pass the result of the function rather than passing the anonymous function, React calls it on every re-render.

Comment: @JMadelaine Thanks for tip i had no idea about it

Answer (score 1):

Extract a custom hook, `useDBStatus()`.

This custom hook abstracts any DB-related communication and just return what's relevant (i.e status).

```
function useDBStatus(ref) {
  const db = firebase.database();
  const [status, setStatus] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (db) {
      db(ref)
        .once("value")
        .then(snapshot => {
          setStatus(/* something */);
        });
    }

    return () => { /* close db connection */ };
  }, [db, ref]);

  return status;
}

function Component() {
  const status = useDBStatus("orders");
  // use status
}
```